# Query Help need with sql Sorting

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table with  roll_no & No_of_items  (Both not primary)

Is it possible to order them the following way: The first entry is with the highest no of items, then all the entries belonging to that roll_no come, then the next entry from a diff roll_no that has the highest no of items and then all the entries belonging to that client and so on

For Eg.

```
Column 1 Column 2
A          12
A          05
C          19
C          18
C          02 
B          05
```

Should display as:

```
C 19
C 18
C 02
A 12
A 05
B 05
```

Comment: What *kind* of SQL? It's much easier in some than others.

Comment: are those contained in the same column? or different columns?

Comment: Different Column, Oracle 10g. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
select t1.*
from yourtable t1
    inner join 
    (
        select 
            client_id, max(numberofdays) cnt 
        from yourtable 
        group by client_id
    ) t2
        on t1.client_id = t2.client_id
order by cnt desc, client_id, numberofdays desc;
```

This may also work, dependant on SQL flavour

```
select *
from yourtable
order by 
    max(numberofdays) over (partition by client_id) desc, 
    client_id, 
    numberofdays desc;
```

Edit: added client_id to order to keep rows with same number.

Answer (score 1):

what you will use in your sql query is 'order by' your code will look like this using MySql

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("select `client_id`, `No_of_Days` FROM `tablename` order by `No_of_Days` DESC ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query))
{
     echo $row->client_id." ".$row->No_of_Days;
}
?>
```

the query is what does the main work here

Comment: This doesn't return the order requested.